# Looks like there is a bug in where clause

Tags: r

Not sure what is happening here. As per the logic, I am not getting the expected output:

```r
ini1 <- c("aB", "cD", "dE", "sP", "sW","sV")
labels1 <- c("AB","CD", "DE", "SP","SW","SV")

refine_colnames <- data.frame(ini1,labels1)

col_name <- c("cD","sW","sV")
col_name_new <- as.character(refine_colnames[which(refine_colnames$ini1 == col_name), "labels1"])
col_name_new
[1] "SW" "SV"
```

Expected output is:

```r
[1] "CD" "SW" "SV"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do:

```
refine_colnames$ini1 == col_name
```

You are asking R to compare these two vectors element by element. But `col_name` is shorter than `refine_colnames$ini1`, so R *recycles* `col_name`. Effectively then, what you are doing is:

```
c("aB", "cD", "dE", "sP", "sW","sV") == c("cD","sW","sV", "cD","sW","sV")
```

You will see that these two vectors only match in the last two positions, which is why you get the output `"sW" "sV"`

What you want is to `match` the two vectors:

```
match(col_name, refine_colnames$ini1)
#> [1] 2 5 6
```

Or even better

```
refine_colnames$labels1[match(col_name, refine_colnames$ini1)]
#> [1] "CD" "SW" "SV"
```